# How can I create a converter?

Tags: types, converters, vaadin, presentation

When I use buildAndBind , Vaadin send me this message:

```
Caused by ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type com.gldos.GCOOP.cliente.Cliente to presentation type class java.lang.String. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
->>   98 | convertFromModel  in com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil
```

I think I need CustomConverter but I have no idea on how to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a converter following this tutorial:

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20your%20own%20converter%20for%20String%20-%20MyType%20conversion